# How to change color of a button, while keeping button's functions in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, button, colors

I already know about custom drawing, owner drawing and subclassing. So far my choice is custom drawing. Subclassing would be my second choice, but the amount of buttons I create is huge. If anyone has any other suggestions, please comment. Anyway I'll just post my code for custom drawing, as there is no direct answer to it anywhere for win32.

Comment: What you should normally do in this situation is ask the question, then answer your own question. Feel free to edit what you have here and add your solution with an explanation as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: You should edit your question so that it is a full question that someone else could write an answer to also (you might learn something).  Right now your question is full of meta-discussion that belongs, at most, in comments -- and will probably lead to its closure as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Nothing is selected]
[image: First button is selected and was pushed]
[image: Second button was pushed and the mouse is over it (notice the increse of brightness - cutom hilight)]

First picture shows when nothing is selected, second shows when first button is selected and was pushed and the last one shows when second button was pushed and the mouse is over it (notice the increase of brightness - cutom hilight). In order to do this, you must catch NM_CUSTOMDRAW message and paint button yourself. And this is how you do it. Also added gradient brush function and some comments.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>

#define IDC_EXIT_BUTTON 101
#define IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON 102

HBRUSH CreateGradientBrush(COLORREF top, COLORREF bottom, LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item)
    {
        HBRUSH Brush = NULL;
        HDC hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(item->hdc);
        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(item->hdc, item->rc.right-item->rc.left, item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top);
        SelectObject(hdcmem, hbitmap);

        int r1 = GetRValue(top), r2 = GetRValue(bottom), g1 = GetGValue(top), g2 = GetGValue(bottom), b1 = GetBValue(top), b2 = GetBValue(bottom);
        for(int i = 0; i < item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top; i++)
        { 
            RECT temp;
            int r,g,b;
            r = int(r1 + double(i * (r2-r1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            g = int(g1 + double(i * (g2-g1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            b = int(b1 + double(i * (b2-b1) / item->rc.bottom-item->rc.top));
            Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r, g, b));
            temp.left = 0;
            temp.top = i;
            temp.right = item->rc.right-item->rc.left;
            temp.bottom = i + 1; 
            FillRect(hdcmem, &temp, Brush);
            DeleteObject(Brush);
        }
        HBRUSH pattern = CreatePatternBrush(hbitmap);

        DeleteDC(hdcmem);
        DeleteObject(Brush);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);

        return pattern;
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBRUSH defaultbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH hotbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH selectbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_uncheckedbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_checkedbrush = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_hotbrush1 = NULL;
    static HBRUSH push_hotbrush2 = NULL;
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                HWND Exit_Button = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"EXIT", 
                                                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
                                                        50, 50, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_EXIT_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
                if(Exit_Button == NULL)
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Button Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                HWND Pushlike_Button = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"PUSH ME!", 
                                                        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE, 
                                                        200, 50, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
                if(Pushlike_Button == NULL)
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Button Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
            }
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            {
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case IDC_EXIT_BUTTON:
                            {
                                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                            }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR some_item = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

            if (some_item->idFrom == IDC_EXIT_BUTTON && some_item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)some_item;

                if (item->uItemState & CDIS_SELECTED)
                {
                    //Select our color when the button is selected
                    if (selectbrush == NULL)
                        selectbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(180, 0, 0), RGB(255, 180, 0), item);

                    //Create pen for button border
                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    //Select our brush into hDC
                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, selectbrush);

                    //If you want rounded button, then use this, otherwise use FillRect().
                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                    //Clean up
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    //Now, I don't want to do anything else myself (draw text) so I use this value for return:
                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    //Let's say I wanted to draw text and stuff, then I would have to do it before return with
                    //DrawText() or other function and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT) //Our mouse is over the button
                    {
                        //Select our color when the mouse hovers our button
                        if (hotbrush == NULL)
                            hotbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 230, 0), RGB(245, 0, 0), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, hotbrush);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }

                    //Select our color when our button is doing nothing
                    if (defaultbrush == NULL)
                        defaultbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 180, 0), RGB(180, 0, 0), item);

                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, defaultbrush);

                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 5, 5);

                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
            }
            else if (some_item->idFrom == IDC_PUSHLIKE_BUTTON && some_item->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW item = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)some_item;

                if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, some_item->idFrom))
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
                    {

                        if (push_hotbrush1 == NULL)
                            push_hotbrush1 = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(0, 0, 245), RGB(0, 230, 255), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_hotbrush1);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }


                    if (push_checkedbrush == NULL)
                        push_checkedbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(0, 0, 180), RGB(0, 222, 200), item);


                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));


                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_checkedbrush);


                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);


                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);


                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item->uItemState & CDIS_HOT)
                    {
                        if (push_hotbrush2 == NULL)
                            push_hotbrush2 = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 230, 0), RGB(245, 0, 0), item);

                        HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                        HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                        HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, push_hotbrush2);

                        RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                        SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                        DeleteObject(pen);

                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                    }

                    if (push_uncheckedbrush == NULL)
                        push_uncheckedbrush = CreateGradientBrush(RGB(255, 180, 0), RGB(180, 0, 0), item);

                    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));

                    HGDIOBJ old_pen = SelectObject(item->hdc, pen);
                    HGDIOBJ old_brush = SelectObject(item->hdc, defaultbrush);

                    RoundRect(item->hdc, item->rc.left, item->rc.top, item->rc.right, item->rc.bottom, 10, 10);

                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_pen);
                    SelectObject(item->hdc, old_brush);
                    DeleteObject(pen);

                    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                }
            }
            return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
        }
        break;
        case WM_CTLCOLORBTN: //In order to make those edges invisble when we use RoundRect(),
            {                //we make the color of our button's background match window's background
                return (LRESULT)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
            }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                DeleteObject(defaultbrush);
                DeleteObject(selectbrush);
                DeleteObject(hotbrush);
                DeleteObject(push_checkedbrush);
                DeleteObject(push_hotbrush1);
                DeleteObject(push_hotbrush2);
                DeleteObject(push_uncheckedbrush);
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    const wchar_t ClassName[] = L"Main_Window";

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = MainWindow;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, ClassName, L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 368, 248, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.message;
}
```

Comment: +1 A great demonstration of what's possible.  I'm not sure I'd want any of my apps to look quite like that, too gaudy, but this is a useful framework for any sort of custom-drawn button.